# Return only count value on _count query

Tags: elasticsearch

Executing the following

http://172.21.21.151:9200/printer-stats-*/_doc/_count

I get the following response

```
{
    "count": 19299,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 44,
        "successful": 44,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    }
}
```

How can i modify the query to only return

```
{
 "count": 19299
}
```

On _search queries we can use filter_path to only get the desired output, but this is not working on count as it seems.

I also tried to add a body like the following

```
{
  "_shards": false
}
```

But it throws the following error

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "request does not support [_shards]",
            "line": 2,
            "col": 3
        }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "request does not support [_shards]",
    "line": 2,
    "col": 3
},
"status": 400
}
```

My version is 7.9.2

Probably this has been asked before, but I have not found a relevant question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter_path` definitely works on the `_count` endpoint:

```
http://172.21.21.151:9200/printer-stats-*/_doc/_count?filter_path=count
```

Response =>

```
{
   "count": 19299
}
```

Comment: You are right. It was a silly mistake on my side. I was running http://172.21.21.151:9200/printer-stats-*/_doc/_count?filter_path=count.count

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!